# Unable to resize image in CSS

Tags: python, css, flask, weasyprint

I am developing a webpage through Flask and would like to generate PDF using WeasyPrint.

I do understand that flask would require static url of defining my css file and include @media print at the css.

```
from 
<link rel=stylesheet href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">

to 

<link rel=stylesheet href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/print.css') }}" media= "print" >

@media print {
logo{
       width : 50px !important;
       height : 100px !important;
       object-fit: cover;
  }
}
```

But it does not appear the resized image to my desired requirements.

Answer (score 2):

This command don't work at weasyprint,

You will need use CSS in Html File.

Like that:

```
<style> /* use CSS into style */
      @page {
        size: A4; /* Change from the default size of A4 */
        margin: 3.5mm; /* Set margin on each page */
      }
       .IMAGE{
        height: 120px;
        width: 120px;
        margin: 0 auto;
       }            
</style>
```

Bye.